# how to keep the newline format when render the rich text to textarea in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a simple rich text that I want to render to UI textarea component, but Now I am facing a issue to handle the rich text which was serialized with the \ and the contains new line symbol `\n`. This is the minimal reproduce code of the issue:

```
import { Form } from "antd";
import TextArea from "antd/es/input/TextArea";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [promptLines, setPromptLines] = useState<string>('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const richtext = `"\"this is the first line\\n\\n* this is the first item.\""`;
    setPromptLines(richtext)
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="outerdiv">
      <Form>
        <Form.Item>
          <TextArea
            id="talkInput"
            value={promptLines}
          ></TextArea>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

how to handle the serialized string properly? how to keep the new line format when render to textarea? What I have tried to replace the special characters like is:

```
const richtext = `"\"this is the first line\\n\\n* this is the first item.\""`;
const textWithoutQuotes = richtext.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
const textToTextArea = textWithoutQuotes.replace(/\\n/g, "&#13;&#10;");
setPromptLines(textToTextArea);
```

and also tried the replace with the `<br/>` like this:

```
const textWithoutQuotes = projectDuty.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
const textToTextArea = textWithoutQuotes.replace(/\\n/g, "<br/>");
```

both could not work.